# Will this cross-domain call with JSONP work when server doesn't support callback function in response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm looking to do a cross-domain call with jQuery and passing parameters via query string to trigger the server to do an action (e.g. send an email, spool up a print job, start the coffee maker). **My problem is that the server doesn't support JSONP responses* and it's not feasible in my time frame to get it changed.**

Assume that my page is hosted in `http://foo.com/test.htm` and the cross domain call is being made to a web-service at http://bar.com/service.svc`.  The URL to kick off an email job is as follows (this is totally fictitious):

```
var mailerUrl = "http://bar.com/service.svc?job=email&to=fred&type=outage";
```

**After thinking about it, I'm wondering whether it actually matters that the server doesn't support JSONP responses since the GET request to the `mailerUrl` is enough to kick the job off.**

The jQuery code would be this (I think):

```
$.getJSON(mailerUrl + "&callback=?", function (json) { });
```

The server will respond with this JSON:

```
{ "d": { "EmailJob": true } }
```

Notice that the response isn't wrapped in a callback function.

The jQuery code ends up bailing after it gets the response since it's not in JSONP format.

However, what I'm wondering is will this succeed cross domain in all the major modern browsers (IE9, Chrome, Firefox4+ and Safari4+)?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: no. Just imagine that any website could load JSON data from your Gmail account just because you are logged in - would be bad, right? So browsers rightfully prevent you from reading JSON data across domains unless the target allows it (via CORS or by supporting a callback).

If the only point is sending a cross-domain GET request without receiving any data then `new Image().src = "http://..."` is the easier way.

Comment: The trouble I'm having with grokking this is due to the order of events.  By the time the browser knows the JSONP response isn't formatted correctly, isn't it too late?  The request has already been made which should trigger my server logic.  I don't think your example with reading Gmail data is the same -- in this case I'm not reading any data, just making a request.

Comment: The request has been made (initiating a cross-domain GET request is easy) but you won't be able to receive any data.

Comment: That's the crux of my question that I tried to be specific about. I don't care about receiving data back, just that the request is succesfully made cross-domain.  So it sounds like your answer should be "Yes" then?

Comment: @TMC: JSON is all about getting data back. If all you care about is sending a request then you can simply use `<img src="http://...">` or `new Image().src = "http://..."` and be done with it.

Comment: I need to make a request at runtime since it's triggered based on user input. Will using ``new Image().src() = "http://..."` work at runtime?

Comment: I'll credit you with the answer if you edit it. It sounds like you're saying that my above code will work but you're recommending a simpler approach with dynamic <img> tags at runtime.

Comment: Ha.  You've still said the "Answer is no", but the answer is actually yes :) It's just more complicated than what you're recommending which is to use an <img> tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you won't be able to do anything with the response, it will likely just be evaluated and thrown away. But if you just want to invoke a service on the remote server there is no reason why this wouldn;t work